# Problems making Grails Spring Security REST work with custom authentication provider

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a project that works with a custom auth provider that let users login with username, password and an organization number. I created my own AuthFilter, AuthProvider and a UserPassOrgAuthToken.

This works like charm login in from the web (Grails Spring Security Core).

Now I need to add security to my REST API under /rest/** and make the same kind of login user+pass+org work to get a JWT.

I installed the plugin, and set some configurations (https://github.com/ppazos/cabolabs-ehrserver/commit/1524ac56971f6e4a613ba1b6778d6fd3f6e368c0) but when I try to POST to /rest/login I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Also, I added some printlns on my provider and filter, and don't seem to be executed at all (see the commit link above).

Please, if you see any misconfigurations, or have any pointers of how to make this work, all comments are very welcome!

EDIT: this is the output from the logs

```
2015-12-10 12:24:00,996 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/rest/login'; against '/rest/**'
2015-12-10 12:24:00,996 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /rest/login at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthFilter'
2015-12-10 12:24:00,996 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /rest/login at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2015-12-10 12:24:00,996 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /rest/login at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
2015-12-10 12:24:01,036 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Actual URI is /rest/login; endpoint URL is /rest/login
2015-12-10 12:24:01,036 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Applying authentication filter to this request
2015-12-10 12:24:01,277 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG credentials.DefaultJsonPayloadCredentialsExtractor  - Extracted credentials from JSON payload. Username: admin, password: [PROTECTED]
2015-12-10 12:24:01,297 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Trying to authenticate the request
2015-12-10 12:24:01,437 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication failed: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
2015-12-10 12:24:01,437 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
2015-12-10 12:24:01,457 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - No token found
2015-12-10 12:24:01,467 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenAuthenticationFailureHandler  - Sending status code 401 and header WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
2015-12-10 12:24:01,467 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Not authenticated. Rest authentication token not generated
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `/rest/login` permission to `permitAll`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
  "/rest/login": ["permitAll"]
]
```

because, starting from spring-security-core version 2.0, all url are protected by default

Comment: GUL, is that needed by the plugin even if the app doesn't use static rules but RequestMap (see Config.groovy grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap) and have new RequestMap(url: '/rest/**', configAttribute: 'permitAll').save() (created on Bootstrap)?

Comment: I've never tried using RequestMap, but I suppose it should work. Usually I use annotation and `staticRules` is the best way to add rules to specific url when using annotation. That's way I've showed you staticRules, but I suppose you can use any method to give `permitAll` permission to login url.

Comment: So I think that is not what is giving the 401, because I already have permitAll for /rest/**, I think that should include also /rest/login (for all the endpoints I already have under /rest/... the permitAll works ok)

Comment: Can you try to increase logging as explained in http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.3/docs/guide/debugging.html, and post logs? Usually it gives useful info to narrow down the problem

Comment: The problem seems to be in `2015-12-10 12:24:01,437 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication failed: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. I've not checked all your source code, but it seems that you haven't separeted filter chains between form-based authentication and rest authentication (see http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.3/docs/guide/configuration.html)

Comment: Looking at the REST security code, I found it's auth filter depends on the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. SInce I have a custom login, I have a custom token: UserPassOrgAuthToken. What I did is extend the filter, now it works ans is generating the JWT. The problem now is that the token verification filter is letting the request pass through all filters and gives an error at the end, even it seems to validate it ok. I'll create another question for that issue since my solution is working ok for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom REST authentication using this guide
https://objectpartners.com/2013/07/11/custom-authentication-with-the-grails-spring-security-core-plugin/

I had an only issue, after verify the user in my CustomProvider the server would return a 'main.gsp'. It happened due to I had the following 2 lines in my CustomFilter.doFilter

```
authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)

chain.doFilter(request, response)
```

I had to remove the first line because the onAuthenticationSuccess is resolved by restAuthenticationFilter.

in my config

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/auth/login': 'myCustomFilter,restAuthenticationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'
]
```